# Resolution Proof Understanding

Tags: logic

If we have a clause like $$(x,y)$$ and $$(x,\neg y)$$ we can derive empty clause but why do we derive the empty clause and not the empty set? When would we derive the empty set?

My question is regarding the difference between an empty SET and CLAUSE not how to derive them. I know how to derive the clauses above. I was just using a previous question as an example.

For example why do we get the symbol on line 7 while in the other picture we get { } on line 5.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Deriving sets from clauses? I'm not getting you here.

Comment: @AlexM. added images for clarity.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: It seems that the OP is asking about the difference between $\{\}$ and $\emptyset$ (see the images), which means that this is not a duplicate of the other (related, indeed) question. To me, the two notations seem identical, I'd say that their author was absent-minded when typing them - but you are the logician, not me, so you should know better.

Comment: As already answered to your previous post, from  $\{ x,y  \}$ and $\{ \lnot x, \lnot y  \}$ you **cannot** derive the *empty clause* because the two clauses are jointly satisfiable.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA sorry added a negation when there wasn't supposed to be one. The images depict it better. Maybe Alex is right that the author meant the two notations to be identical and if that is the case then that answers my question although I would like confirmation if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that it is only a question of "sloppiness"...

There is no

> difference between an *empty set* and the *empty clause*

in [resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_(logic)).

> The [empty clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clause_(logic)#Empty_clauses) is denoted by various symbols such as $\emptyset, \bot$, or $\Box$. The truth evaluation of an empty clause is always *false*.

Comment: Thank you, appreciate the patience. The constant use of different notations that mean the same thing confuses me.